# Spring: overriding one application.property from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application.properties file with default variable values. I want to be able to change ONE of them upon running with `mvn spring-boot:run`. I found how to change the whole file, but I only want to change one or two of these properties.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can pass in individual properties as command-line arguments. For example, if you wanted to set `server.port`, you could do the following when launching an executable jar:

```
java -jar your-app.jar --server.port=8081
```

Alternatively, if you're using `mvn spring-boot:run` with Spring boot 2.x:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8081"
```

Or, if you're using Spring Boot 1.x:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=8081"
```

You can also configure the arguments for `spring-boot:run` in your application's `pom.xml` so they don't have to be specified on the command line every time:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--server.port=8085</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @yuli I've edited your question and updated my answer with some options for when you're using `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: I get `org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: "--server.port=8181" is not a valid option`

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't use args4j, so that failure must be coming from your code

Comment: Note that:
1. Arguments should be comma separated
2. Each argument should be prefixed with --
eg.
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8081,--customArgument=custom"

Comment: if the argument is a custom argument inside application.properties, say myValue, will it still work?

Comment: This worked for me 

java -jar -D"server.port=8081" your-app.jar

Answer (score 23):

To update a little things, the Spring boot 1.X Maven plugin relies on the `--Drun.arguments` Maven user property but the Spring Boot 2.X Maven plugin relies on the `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments` Maven user property.

So for Spring 2, you need to do :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8081"
```

And if you need to pass multiple arguments, you have to use `,` as separator and never use whitespace between arguments :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8081,--foo=bar"
```

About the the maven plugin configuration and the way of passing the argument from a fat jar, it didn't change.
So the very good Andy Wilkinson answer is still right.

Comment: Cool!.  System properties like -Dproperty1=value1 -Dproperty2=value2 can also be passed on the command line via
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--property1=value1,--property2=value2"

Comment: Not working for me. If I put a whitespace the application will not detect the arguments, and if I put a whitespace the SDK will not read it. Still looking for how to add application.properties args.

Answer (score 23):

Quick update:

if you are  using the  latest versions of  spring-boot 2.X  and maven 3.X, the below  command  line will override  your server port:

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=9999   your_jar_file.jar
```

Comment: Why in the world did they change it to this syntax of all things? -D?

Comment: They're not defining that syntax.  That's the `java` executable's syntax for defining *system properties* (the kind you can get from System.getProperty()).  Spring just grabs those in addition to its other sources.

Answer (score 10):

You can set an environment variable to orverride the properties. For example, you have an property name `test.props=1` . If you have an environment variable `TEST_PROPS` spring boot will automatically override it.

```
export TEST_PROPS=2
mvn spring-boot:run
```

You can also create a json string with all the properties you need to override and pass it with `-Dspring.application.json` or export the json with `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.application.json='{"test.props":"2"}'
```

Or just pass the properties with -Dtest.props=2

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dtest.props=2
```

Tested on spring boot `2.1.17` and maven `3.6.3`

Answer (score 7):

If not working with comma, to override some custom properties or spring boot properties in multiple mode, use whitespace instead of comma, like this code bellow:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8899 --your.custom.property=custom"
```

Comment: Finally somebody has posted proper way to do it with double "-": `--your.custom.property=value`. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

**Running by Gradle:**

- **Run in default port(8080):** `./gradlew bootRun`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `./gradlew bootRun --args='--server.port=8888'`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `PORT=8888 ./gradlew bootRun`

**Running by Maven:**

- **Run in default port(8080):** `mvnw spring-boot:run`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8085'`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--server.port=8085'`
- **Run in provided port(8888) with other custom property:** `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8899 --your.custom.property=custom"`
- If we have any variable in the `application.properties` file named `PORT`, run this: `SERVER_PORT=9093 mvn spring-boot:run`

**Using `java -jar`:**

- **Create the .jar file:**

  - For Gradle: `./gradlew clean build`. We will find the jar file inside: `build/libs/` folder.
  - For Maven: `mvn clean install`. We will find the jar file inside:`target` folder.
- **Run in default port(8080):** `java -jar myApplication. jar`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `java -jar myApplication.jar --port=8888`
- **Run in provided port(8888):** `java -jar -Dserver.port=8888  myApplication.jar`
- **Run in provided port(8888) having variable `SERVER_PORT` in application.properties file:** `SERVER_PORT=8888 java -jar target/myApplication.jar`

Answer (score 2):

If you have the jar file after doing mvn clean install, you can override any property that you have in your application.yml using the double -, like this:

```
java -jar name_of_your_jar_file.jar --parameter=value
```

For example, if you need to change your server port when starting you server, you can write the following:

```
java -jar name_of_your_jar_file.jar --server.port=8888
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot we have provision to override properties as below

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8082`

Answer (score 0):

I Was making a mistake with the syntax of commandline command , while passing command-line arguments, I was wrapping multiple arguments between " " and this was the issue. I simply ran the same command having multiple arguments separated by a space without wraaping them between "" and it worked just fine.

*Please note this answer is for cases where we are trying to run this scenario from a jar file(not using mvn).*

**Correct Command: java -jar myJar.jar --com.arg1=10 --com.arg2=1**

**Incorrect Command: java -jar myJar.jar "--com.arg1=10 --com.arg2=1"**