# Override application.yml with environment variable in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need my application should pick the value of a key from environment variables instead of `application.yml`.

1. If a particular property is available in both environment variables and in `application.yml`, then it should pick the value specified as part of environment variables.
2. If a particular property is not there in environment variables then it should pick a value from `application.yml` else not.

Comment: This is the default behavior of spring. Doesn't it work for you out of the box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: overriding one application.property from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052857/spring-overriding-one-application-property-from-command-line)

Answer (score -1):

For your two questions. You can use something like:

```
spring:
  profiles: ${YOUR_ENV_FOR_PROFILE:YOUR_DEFAULT_PROFILE}
```

If you set an environment variable(Ex. YOUR_ENV_FOR_PROFILE) then spring use it, otherwise spring use a default value "YOUR_DEFAULT_PROFILE"

Comment: Why complicate things? This should run out of the box in Spring Boot. No need for complex syntax here.