# Using Karate, can the .feature Mock files intercept calls from back-end Java service class?

Tags: karate

Question about Karate: can the .feature Mock files intercept calls from back-end Java service class?

I think the mocking feature is pretty easy to understand.   I can see that you can start the mock server in the background step and then your scenario HTTP calls will be intercepted BUT

My question is: is it possible to intercept HTTP calls coming from my back-end service class after I hit my API endpoint with a Karate step?

If I don't get an answer, I will put together a sample project and experiment.   Just hoping someone knows off-hand.   If not, I think I can probably run an instance of Mountebank.

Comment: yeah, mountebank sounds like a good choice. go for it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible by telling the JVM to use an HTTP proxy, but it depends a lot on the system under test.

You can find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61414022/143475

Comment: Thanks.  I think I can do it with WireMock possibly.  Thanks.