run an automated integration test on an application with multiple modules
my application has 4 nodes. Node A and Node B are the SUTs. communication between those nodes is based on http protocol. The scenario as shown in the picture will be automatically done by the nodes once Node A starts sending the first Request message to Node B.
i would like to create an automated tests (using Maven and Java) which will verify each Request message will receive desired Response message. Besides that the automated test will verify the scenario is successful when Node A receives Resp 201 from Node D.
i am fairly new in automated QA testing. All this while I have been using Karate to perform automated test. From my limited knowledge on Karate, I use it to verify single node where Karate will send Request message and verify the response.
For this test scenario, Node A will send Request by itself to start the scenario.
There are few Java library for capturing packets (pcap4j, jnetpcap) that can probe each node and inspect the packets but I am looking other alternative which is more efficient. Besides using pcap4j or jnetpcap, is there any better way to test this scenario?


What exactly your question is?

agree that the question is not clear. there is no "magic" for testing, most teams are happy to set up a test-env where all of A, B, C and D are available. now, if you are willing to invest time in creating mocks, then I think the answer to your question is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61414022/143475

Besides using pcap4j or jnetpcap, is there any better way to test this scenario? edited the above post to add a clearer question to the sentence.
