# How can I pass values to @ComponentScan through terminal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a use case where I only want to execute some packages in my SpringBoot application. So, in my main class, I am using something like this -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
  }
}
```

So, here I have hardcoded the basePackages as "com.example". This is not what I want. I want to receive the package name when the application is run from the terminal through command-line arguments.
Is there a way I can pass command-line arguments to the application and use the arguments that I receive inside the basePackages?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to do it based on packages? It is easier to assign components to a profile and start with a certain profile to enable/disable a set of Spring components. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: So, can I pass the value to "spring.profiles.active" through the command line? If yes, can you give me a sample code. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot on how to activate profiles from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use placeholder for this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="${scan.myPackage}")
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
  }
}
```

and on terminal, you can do:

```
java -jar app.jar --scan.myPackage=com.example
```

You may want to learn about *[profiles](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)*.

**Edit:**

From [Spring Boot 2.x and Maven 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407880/8746228) and above, the command to supply dynamic values is:

```
java -jar -Dscan.myPackage=com.example app.jar
```

Comment: Excuse me, if I sound stupid. So, this will work for spring-boot as well, right? Also, how can I run if I don't have jar currently?

Comment: @TrayambakKumar *I want to receive the package name when the application is run from the terminal through command-line arguments*: If you don't have the `jar`, what would be *running* form terminal :) ?

Comment: I wanted something like this(mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--scan.myPackage=com.example" ). But your answer showed me the path. Thank you so much