# Override default spring boot application.properties with application.properties through cmd dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to override properties defined in `application.properties` through cmd with existing other in `application.properties` , but `@Scheduled` only allows to provide predefined values.

What I need is to pass the argument for `@Scheduled` through command line which already exists in `application.properties` and It will going to change the default value defined in `@Scheduled`.

My question is that when I am executing jar file from cmd It is taking value present in `@Scheduled` at the time of build. It is not overriding the existing value `@Scheduled` value. I want to override value as per user need.

spring code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class PSchedularApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String s : args)
            System.out.println("arguments passed=>"+s);
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(PSchedularApplication .class);
        if(!(args).equals(null))
        {
            application.setAddCommandLineProperties(true);
        }
        application.run(args);
    }
}

@Component  
public class TaskSchedular {
@Scheduled(cron="${cronExpression}")
    public void taskScheduling()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to task schedular " + new java.util.Date());
        moveFile();
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
cronExpression=0 0/1 * * * *
pzsc.poll.cron.weekly=0 0/2 * * * *
pzsc.poll.cron.daily=0/30 * * * * *
```

in cmd

```
java -jar PSchedular-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --cron=cronExpression
```

Comment: Well for starters `--cron=cronExpression` should be `--cronExpression=your-expression`, it should match the name of the attribute to provide the schedule. Also this is already supported out of the box, so the "clever"  code you wrote in your main, doesn't actually help, it only complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways of doing this, but one way I can think of is to use externalized application properties file. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files for more specific details.

You would have your `application.properties` (under `src/main/resources`) with the default property `cronExpression`. But when you invoke the JAR, you could pass in a system property to tell Spring where an additional properties file is with possible overrides for that `cronExpression` property.

```
java -jar <jar_name> -Dspring.config.additional-location=my-other-file.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=9999   your_jar_file.jar
```

Please take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052857/spring-overriding-one-application-property-from-command-line). There's a many example.