# Java yaml env variable or default map

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml, environment-variables

I have a map in my YAML file:

```
custom:
 map:
  '[A]': B
```

But in some situations, I would like to set this map with an env variable value. Let's say we have:

```
export ENV_VAR="key:value"
```

YAML file allows us to use env variable interchangeably with some default value, here's an example with a single field key-value:

```
custom:
 uri: ${ENV_VAR:https://google.com}
```

---

So, the question here is how can I use the env variable in YAML interchangeably with the default value for maps?
**The code I want to work out**:

```
custom:
 map: ${ENV_VAR:'[key]':value}
```

Comment: Maybe you can pass the default value as a JSON-like string, see this answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61535146/5612858

Comment: See this: https://dev.kuffel.io/env-variables-spring-default/ and check if it helps or not.

Comment: @pringi, unfortunately, it didn't work out. We have here map structure, not the single field

Comment: Why don't you put the default value in yaml, and override the property in the environment variable? Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052857/spring-overriding-one-application-property-from-command-line

Comment: @Arnaud, using such construction I got a compile error in the YAML file, after colon

Comment: In your environment, export CUSTOM_URI="key:value" and in you yaml, custom:map: '[key]':value

Comment: That makes sense @pringi, the only problem, is that Java cannot parse that: No converter found capable of converting from type String to Map<String, String>. This construction ENV_VAR="key:value" cannot be converted to Map